# Add prefix and suffix to every line in a .txt file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I am trying to append and prepend text to every line in a .txt file.

I want to prepend: `I am a`

I want to append:  `128... [}`

to every line.

Inside of a.txt:

```
fruit, like
bike, like
dino, like
```

Upon performing the following command:

```
$ cat a.txt|sed 'I am a ',' 128... [}'
```

it does not work how I want it to. I would really want it to say the following:

```
I am a fruit, like 128... [}
I am a bike, like 128... [}
I am a dino, like 128... [}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simple **`sed`** approach:

```
sed 's/^/I am a /; s/$/ 128... [}/' file.txt
```

- `^` - stands for *start of the string/line*
- `$` - stands for *end of the string/line*

The output:

```
I am a fruit, like 128... [}
I am a bike, like 128... [}
I am a dino, like 128... [}
```

---

Alternatively, with **`Awk`** you could do:

```
awk '{ print "I am a", $0, "128... [}" }' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks, mate. is it safe to do this? `sed 's/^/^.{128}  /; s/$/$/'` I want to add  `^.{128}` to the beginning and `$` to the end.

Comment: @Terkey-Juice Do you want to actually add a literal "^" to the beginning of each line? If so, that should do it. But you should *always* have a backup of files that you're going to try something on, because things *will* go wrong sometimes.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Hi. Yes, a literal `^`. And I always keep backups of things. Always. Thank you friend

Comment: If the lines/files get big enough to notice, then the awk solution should be more efficient.

Comment: @OrangeDog Big enough to notice? Do you mean if it runs too slow, the `awk` solution would be faster?

Comment: Yes, the sed processes each line twice (making copies) while the awk only once.

Comment: It should be noted that this method doesn't support variable substitution. If you wanted to expand variables you would have to use double quotes `" "` rather than single quotes `' '`. This would change the functionality of the `$` operator. If you also want variable substitution, use the following method:


`sed "s/.*/${var1}&${var2}/"`

Answer (score 10):

```
sed 's/.*/PREFIX&SUFFIX/' infile
```

will do, assuming `PREFIX` and `SUFFIX` don't contain any special characters.

---

`\&/` (backslash, ampersand and delimiter) are special when in the right hand side of a `s`ubstitution. The special meaning of those characters can be suppressed by escaping them (preceding them by a backslash) e.g. to prepend `A//BC` and to append `XY\Z&&` one would run:

```
sed 's/.*/A\/\/BC&XY\\Z\&\&/' infile
```

Comment: I like this method because it supports variable substitution for the prefix and suffix. E.g.

`sed "s/.*/${var1}&${var2}/"`

Answer (score 3):

Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'print "I am a $_ 128... [}"' file 
I am a fruit, like 128... [}
I am a bike, like 128... [}
I am a dino, like 128... [}
```

More Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^/I am a /; s/$/ 128... [}/' file 
I am a fruit, like 128... [}
I am a bike, like 128... [}
I am a dino, like 128... [}
```

And a bit more Perl:

```
$ perl -lpe '$_="I am a $_ 128... [}"' file 
I am a fruit, like 128... [}
I am a bike, like 128... [}
I am a dino, like 128... [}
```

For all of these, you can use `-i` to make the change in the original file:

```
$ perl -i -lne 'print "I am a $_ 128... [}"' file 
$ perl -i -pe 's/^/I am a /; s/$/ 128... [}/' file 
$ perl -i -lpe '$_="I am a $_ 128... [}"' file
```

Comment: How do you do it without the space? e.g. this line works `$ echo xxx|perl -lne 'print "abc $_ kljlkj "'`    It puts that text before and after xxx. But suppose I want to do that without space.   This `$ echo xxx|perl -lne 'print "abc$_kljlkj "'`   doesn't work it just prints 'abc'.

Comment: @barlop you just need to separate the `$_` from any subsequent characters so that perl can recognize the variable name. Any of these would work `print "abc$_"; print "kljlkj "` or `print "abc " . $_ . "kljlkj "` or `print "abc${_}kljlkj"`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative sed

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/I am a \1 128 [{/
```

It searches for everything `.*` between the start `^`, and end of line `$`, and places it in a group `\( \)`. It then replaces it with the prefix, the (first) group `\1`, and the suffix.